# How to solve Python3 Error AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'glob'

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am programming a  Discord Bot right now and
i dont know how to solve the following problem/error:

```
"AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'glob'"
```

**This is my Code:**

```
elif '!meme' in message.content:
    random_message_i = ["Hier das passt zu dir:", "Hier bitte du Knecht:", "Hier... keko:",
                        "Ein Meme für das Meme:", "Gönn dir:", "Einfach wild xD:"]
    await message.channel.send(f"{random.choice(random_message_i)}")
    meme_file_paths = [os.path.abspath(_) for _ in glob.glob("memes/*.png")]
    random_meme_i = random.choice(meme_file_paths)
    await message.channel.send(file=discord.File(random_meme_i))
    print("Last command: !meme")
```

****This is the Error Message:****

```
C:\Users\cxyro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in run_event await coro(*args, **kwargs) File "c:\Users\cxyro\Desktop\DiscordBot\discordbot.py", line 105, in on_message meme_file_paths = [os.path.abspath() for _ in glob.glob("memes/*.png")] AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'glob'
```

**My Folder Structure:**

```
C:.
├───.idea
│   └───inspectionProfiles
├───Backups
├───Project
├───memes
└───Discordbot.py
```

Can anybody help me?

Thanks! :D

Comment: did you do `import glob` or `from glob import glob`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `glob.glob("memes/*.png")`, what do you expect this to mean? Why? In particular: what do you expect the first `glob` to refer to, and what do you expect the `.glob` part to do?

Comment: `glob` in your global namespace is already the function `glob` (because you did `from glob import glob`).  Change `glob.glob(...)` in your code to just `glob(...)`.